# How to generate permanent access token for GCP APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, authorization, gcloud

We are trying to upload files to GCP bucket using the below `cURL`

```
curl -v --location --request POST 'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<bucketName>/o?uploadType=media&name=<path>' --header "Authorization: $AUTH_HEADER" --header 'Content-Type: application/java-archive' --data-binary '@'${OBJECT_NAME}
```

Currently we are generating **AUTH_HEADER** using `gcloud auth print-access-token` but this seems like a short lived token. Is there any way we can generate permanent token? Actually we are trying to automate upload process using CI/CD pipelines. If we could get a permanent access token we can encrypt and use it on the CI job itself.

Comment: You can increase the duration up to 12h, not more

Answer (score 2):

access tokens are short lived by design.  It comes back to the fact that access tokens are bearer tokens and will work for the bearer of the token until the token has expired with out any extra security checking.   This means if you have a permeant access token and its stolen then the person stealing it is

Comment: Provide tips for best practice for a application that have to make continuous API calls to Google?

Comment: @momo668 try to use the same refresh token for 50 minutes then request a new one.